# jquery modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Never used jquery modals before and I can't quite get this to work. Any suggestions?

I'm getting "undefined is not a function" for "$('#dialog').dialog({"

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Enter your Email Address">Please enter your email address</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
$(".input").click(function() {
    console.log("Notify Me");

    var emailAdd = $(".form").val();

    if (emailAdd.length <5) {

       $(function(){
            // jQuery UI Dialog
            $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(location).attr('href',$(this).dialog('option', 'anchor'));
            return true;
            },
            "No": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return false;
            }
            }
            });

            $('.closebutton').click(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'anchor', $(this).attr('href'));
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
            });
            }); 



    } else {

            Some function
    }
```

Comment: This means you either did not include the script that contains the code for dialog() or you did not include jQuery itself. It's undefined because one of those is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$(function(){
$(".input").click(function() {
console.log("Notify Me");
var emailAdd = $(".form").val();
if (emailAdd.length <5) {
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
}
});
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EHhk6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/937kH/31/)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
  {
     ShowDialog(false);
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnShowModal").click(function (e)
  {
     ShowDialog(true);
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
  {
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
  {
     var brand = $("#brands input:radio:checked").val();
     $("#output").html("<b>Your favorite mobile brand: </b>" + brand);
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();
  });

 });

function ShowDialog(modal)
{
  $("#overlay").show();
  $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);

  if (modal)
  {
     $("#overlay").unbind("click");
  }
  else
  {
     $("#overlay").click(function (e)
     {
        HideDialog();
     });
  }
}

function HideDialog()
 {
  $("#overlay").hide();
  $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
 }
```